# Fix canvas warping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why does canvas stretch the contents when you resize it and how can I account for this happening?

Comment: That's the standard behavior. The only thing you can do is to set its `width` and `height` using CSS so that it can't be resized.

Comment: What @MisterJack said, though you may also have situation to bind to window.onresize event and handle it however you want (depends what is causing your canvas to resize).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you specify? What kind of canvas?
For what I understand, I assume you are looking for manipulating the resize property of an element.

You can change this by specifying the object's resize propery:

```
<textarea style="resize: none;">
</textarea>
```

Unfortunately, this is a CSS3 property so only Mozilla and Webkit can support the resize property. You can check this out in http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp

Allowed resize: none | both | horizontal | vertical